# custom js/css file not getting called through phtml- 404 error

Tags: magento2

Im trying to creating a custom js file in my custom module.

This is what i have tried.

**\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        test:  'Vendor_Module/js/test'
       }
     }
};
```

**\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
     <link src="Vendor_Module::test.js"/>
     <css src="Vendor_Module::test.css"/>
 </head>
<body/>
</page>
```

**\view\frontend\web\js\test.js**

Here i have few functions already in test.js, but need suggestion here as to how to proceed.

I have done as follows.How to proceed here!

```
define([
'jquery',
'jquery/ui'
], function($){
 $.widget ('mage.test',{
    _create: function() {
        if (console) {
            console.log(this.element);
        }
    }
});
 //return $.mage.test;
//});

function extend(t, e){

 ...}   // should the extend() be within the function($){..} ?
```

Im calling my js thru html as :

**view\frontend\templates\js.phtml**

```
<div data-mage-init='{"test":{}}'></div>
<script>
   ....    
</script>
```

I get this error! Which says my js is not loaded, is the way what i have called from js.phtml rite?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `pub/static` folder and run command 
`php bin/magento static-content:deploy` from your terminal.

Comment: I tried that, also cleared cache, but still js doesnt seems to load...am i calling it properly from html?